# Windows.h functions not declared - C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm trying to write a test program using windows.h. I have a simple main function with a function in it and doesn't work when I compile it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    COORD coords;
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &coords);
    
    return 0;

}
```

But when I compile it using "mingw32-gcc main.c" i get:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:107:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SetConsoleDisplayMode' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &coords);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:107:60: error: 'CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE' undeclared (first use in this function)
     SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &coords);
                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:107:60: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function
```

(It says it's in line 107 because I wrote additional functions that does not need windows.h and don't cause trouble as I don't use them, also they are commented)

Comment: It's missing a semicolon`;` but apart from that MS VC compiles the code.

Comment: Are you sure it's an "undeclared" error and not "undefined"? Undefined would be a missing library needing to be specified as part of your build command.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it from my phone and I forgot the semicolon, but in the code it is written. And the error is exactly: main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:107:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SetConsoleDisplayMode' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, NULL);
  
main.c:107:60: error: 'CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE' undeclared (first use in this function)
     SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &NULL);

Comment: Please edit that into the question. And please don't guess the code or the errors. `&NULL` shown in the supposed error isn't in the code. Copy/paste everything exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the edit button, I saw it now I'm gonna edit it

Comment: *it's in line 107 because I wrote additional functions that does not need windows.h* So how do we know that the code you didn't show, which gave that error, contains `#include <windows.h>`? The error suggests it did not, but strangely, there is no error reported for `COORD coords;`

Comment: Because the code is basically write and read from files functions and it is commented all what is not the main shown up there, and yeah it's weird that COORD is detected :S

Comment: Have you tried explicitly including the headers mentioned in the [SetConsoleDisplayMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoledisplaymode) man page, which are supposedly included by `windows.h`? Your `COORD` and `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` compiled, but the `CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE` and `SetConsoleDisplayMode` did not.

Comment: I have tried it now including wincon.h and still says the same. In the man page also appears something called ConsoleApi3.h but i can't find it anywhere, maybe that's the problem? if it is, how can it be solved?

Comment: Works for me, MinGW64 with GCC 8.1.0 on Win10.

Comment: I updated the Windows SDK and i have now found the consoleapi3.h file, but my mingw32-gcc doesn't find the file consoleapi3.h even though it is in D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\consoleapi3.h (I tried including the full D:\Windows... but the consoleapi3.h file also includes apiset.h and also it does not find it)